# PrettyPhoto - how to track when user closes the modal box

Tags: javascript, jquery, prettyphoto

I am using pretty photo to display videos - It pretty much works as the demo on the prettyphoto website

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto

If you look at the first demo - on my website - a similar window opens up but instead of an image a video is played.

Now on this window, there is this small "x" on the bottom right corner. So when a user clicks on close - I want to track it. Basically when a user clicks on close - a jquery function should be triggered using which I can call a server side script.

This is my current setup

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
<script src="/js/jquery.prettyPhoto2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
  });
</script>


<a href="/course/play-video/topic_id/topic_id;?>?iframe=true&width=470&height=340" rel="prettyPhoto" title="topic_name;?>">
<img src="/images/videos/" width="170" height="103" alt="topic_name;?>"/>
</a>
```

But how do I track when the user clicks on close and is there anyway to pass the topic id to that function
Thanks much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the documentation is a line you can add for customizing:

```
callback: function(){}, /* Called when prettyPhoto is closed */
```

and within that you can put what you want like:

```
callback: function() { alert('Prettyphoto closed'); }
```

You can see the example they use here, http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation/

Comment: Thanks Scott - thats exactly what I was looking for. Just one more thing - each link has a unique topic_id - is there anyway I can pass this topic_id to this callback function.

Comment: You could see what $(this) produces within that function, but I think that will refer to the gallery as a whole and the documentation doesn't specify a public function that could do such. So if that doesn't work, when the picture is changed you can store it somewhere like changepicturecallback: function(){ $('#current_topic_hidden_element').text($(this).attr('href')); } and then on the callback function, get $('#current_topic_hidden_element').text() again (you will need an element on the page with id="current_topic_hidden_element" to store that...)

Comment: hmm so the changepicturecallback would be called when the picture changes right - so in my case only one video is played - would this function even be called. Secondly I was wondering if I add the topic_id as part of the href like href="/course/play-video/topic_id/topic_id;?>?topic_id=15&iframe=true&width=470&height=340" - would it be possible to get it in the callback function. Thanks for your time

Comment: I did try that but $(this).attr('href') is undefined it says

Comment: I think this is a different question - I will post it as a new one . Thanks